# Как обрезать значение переменной

Tags: java, android, строки

Есть 2 переменные:

```
String one = "123456789";
String two = "";
```

Мне нужно скопировать значение переменной `one` в переменную `two`, начиная с 5 знака.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 5):

Можно воспользоваться методом `substring(int beginIndex)` класса `String`.

Если с 5 знака (включительно), то:

```
String one = "123456789";
String two = one.substring(4);
```